# Laravel mail not working but password reset email does

Tags: php, laravel, email, ubuntu, notifications

I have a Laravel 5.4 app that sends email upon user registration. It works perfect using homestead and mailtrap. I've moved it to a Google Cloud VPS, and now those emails are not going out. But, the strange part is that emails for forgotten Password Resets does.

Making a further research I have noticed that the emails for registration are based on [Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail) while those for Password Reset on [Laravel Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#mail-notifications)

Some posts suggest that I should use Sendgrid for this, but if that were the case I shouldn't be receiving any email in Mailtrap inbox at all.